# Problem installing Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, python

I am getting a python version error while installing web3js from npm

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/anaconda3/bin/python" is v3.6.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
```

Is there any way of installing web@1.0.0 and better version while working on python3 only

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by `node-gyp`. You can try `npm config set python python2.7` or if you have node-gyp installed `node-gyp --python=python2.7` or create a new conda env with python v2.7 and try executing the command within that env.